# Burger King’s expanded its Royal Perks rewards program

Tags: punctuation

Is the apostrophe 's incorrect after "Burger King"? The sentence comes from CNN.

> Burger King’s expanded its Royal Perks rewards program nationwide earlier this year.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conventional contraction of **Burger King *has* expanded** and reflects the way people speak in everyday conversation.

It is a very casual spelling. I would be unsurprised to read this in a novel. I would be very surprised to read it in an academic paper. Because of the topic, I imagine CNN was going for popular appeal.

I agree that pairing the present perfect tense with **earlier this year** sounds a little off. I would have chosen the simple past tense.

Comment: Does "earlier this year" call for the past tense?

Comment: I've added an edit.

Comment: I only suppose this happens when writing based on how words are spoken. For something meant to be read, it can become confusing for the reader. Because possibly they meant "Burger King’s expanded Royal Perks" vs. "Burger King has expanded its Royal Perks"

Comment: @user3169 - I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to make there. Without a doubt the original is one ugly casting of a sentence, whether they consider the 's to be a contraction of 'has' or 'is' . "Burger King expanded…" would be far simpler & less contentious.